# spring boot rest and jackson epoch parsing for OffsetDateTime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I have following rest controller method.

```java
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<OffsetDateTime> setTime(@RequestBody SetTimeRequest request) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(request.getTime());
}
```

and following is the request body

```java
public static class SetTimeRequest {
    private OffsetDateTime time;
    public OffsetDateTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(OffsetDateTime time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

when I send from postman request like this:

```json
{
  "time": "1641994507692"
}
```

the result is `+54002-09-26T03:28:12+02:00` however it should be `2022-01-12T14:35:07.692+01:00`.

I've seen that it's possible to change deserializer property `READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS` however I'm not pretty sure if that's a good solution.

Is it a bug, or is it by design?

**EDIT**:
spring boot 2.6.2 and same issue in 2.5.4

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: good point...I've modified the question

Comment: 1. `1641994507692` *is* "about 2022/01/12" *in milliseconds* not in nanos! 2. Why string (why not numeric!??) ? Can you "fix the format" or you do you have to "fix the (de-)serialization"?

Comment: I know that's in millis, but why spring is trying to convert it from nanos? I mean if that's allowed by default to pass there also some number instead of properly formatted string then it's probably not correct. I can put there some custom serializer.

Comment: Somewhere in your project it has been defined a SetTimeRequest deserializer or a converter, please include the code in the question.

Comment: you name it: OR number OR "properly formatted string" (in json it is a a difference) ...and `+54002-09-26T03:28:12+02:00` comes out, when we treat  it as `"1641994507692"` (string)...

Comment: please also consider to answer my questions: why is it string? can we change this?

Comment: the fix should be the deserialization. I'm not quite sure why spring allows to deserialize the date from number even when it's `OffsetDateTime` which should be in some format.